# How to get tokens valid for longer than 24h

Tags: google-sheets-api, oauth2-playground

I'm trying to get a token valid for a long time and I am not sure how to proceed.
I'm sending data to a Google Sheet on a daily basis so a 24h token doesn't allow me to have this automated.

Thanks

Comment: What code have you used ? and have you used https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts ? and the have you tested it with the offered quickstart exemple ?

Answer (score 1):

I have since found a way to make my script work. In the script, do not include the access token, ONLY the refresh token.

By having both, it prevented the refresh token of getting a new token and was simply using the expired token.

Answer (score 0):

The generic way of obtaining tokens expiring longer than 24 hours is to get a refresh token. You can start by reading the instructions here:

[Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration)

[Get Refresh Tokens](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/refresh-tokens/get-refresh-token/)

[Refreshing Access Tokens](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/refreshing-access-tokens/)